# How do I link all the UISlider events to one method?

Tags: ios, slider, uislider, uievent

I have the following method in my view-controller:

```
- (IBAction)itemSlider:(UISlider *)itemSlider withEvent:(UIEvent*)e;
{
    UITouch * touch = [e.allTouches anyObject];

    if( touch.phase != UITouchPhaseMoved && touch.phase != UITouchPhaseBegan)
    {
    }
    else if( touch.phase != UITouchPhaseMoved && touch.phase != UITouchPhaseBegan)
    {
    }
   ... 
}
```

Do I really need to link all the events one by one to my controller?

Comment: what events do you need to capture on your UISlider?

Comment: I wanted to capture them all.
Anyway, value changed make the work I think.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are seeking to capture the value changed on slider , then you may follow up the below tutorials instead of using touch events.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/better-code-uislider-basics-for-apple-ios/

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm new in the site so didn't have enough reputation to vote up for your answer.